# Use jQuery to hide a div until multiple check boxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use jQuery to hide a div until all five check boxes below are selected. I know how to do this for a single check box but not for multiple check boxes.

This is what I have so far.

```
<input type=checkbox id="cb1" name="cb1">
<input type=checkbox id="cb2" name="cb2">
<input type=checkbox id="cb3" name="cb3">
<input type=checkbox id="cb4" name="cb4">
<input type=checkbox id="cb5" name="cb5">

<div id="hidden">some stuff</div>
```

jQuery below only hides/shows div if one check box is unselected/selected.

```
('#hidden').hide();
$('#cb1').click(function() {
    if($('#cb1').is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }   
});
```

Comment: Do you want to show the div when all checkboxes are checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a common class to checkboxes it may help if other checkboxes exist in page. For simplification I am using $(':checkbox') selector

```
var $checks=$(':checkbox').change(function(){
      var allChecked= $checks.filter(':checked').length == $checks.length;
    $('#hidden').toggle( allChecked); /*passing a boolean will tell whether to hide or show*/

})
```

Comment: Upvoting for `change` and `toggle`. `filter` is nice as well.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the code, this does what I want it to do. I added a common class as you suggested.

Comment: Is change ok these days? I would expect click, since change used to mean a blur was needed

Comment: I have used `change` for years with jQuery on checkbox and radios. I had some problems a long time ago in IE with `click`. It will register at time of clcik

Answer (score 2):

Here we click any of the checks that start with cb - toggle from other answer

```
$(function() {
  var CBS = $('input[name^="cb"]');
  CBS.click(function() {
    var show = $('input[name^="cb"]:checked').length==CBS.length;
    $('#hidden').toggle(show); // better solution than show/hide
  }​);​
}​);​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8uxTW/)

Comment: $%^# it, i was answering that, :P

Answer (score 2):

If all checkboxes should be checked, use this code:

```
if ($('input:checked').length === 5 /* number of checkboxes */) { ... }
```

If some of them should be:

```
var checkedIds = $('input:checked').map(function() {
   return this.id;
}).get();
var neededIds = ['ch1', 'ch2' /*, ... */];
if (checkedIds.toString() === neededIds.toString()) { ... }
```

Comment: why did you put ===, I mean three equal signs

Comment: why not? It's just a habbit to use strong equals if it is possible :)

Comment: @defau1t `===` means "equal and of same type"; `==` means "equal after type coersion". The former is "safer" and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$('[id^=cb]').click(function() {
    if(! $('[id^=cb]:not(:checked)').length)
    {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }   
});
```

Here we use `` `[id^=cb] `` to select all your elements with id starting in "cb" string, and then for any click of them we just check if there's any of them unchecked, if not, then show your div.

**UPDATE:** Updated my code above to support the fact there's no `:unchecked` selector in jQuery, instead `:not(:checked)` have to be used. Thanks KirillIvlev for noting this.

Comment: Why check on the id instead of the type? ```input[type="checkbox"]```

Comment: there's no such thing as :unchecked selector

Comment: `is()` won't loop the collection, use `filter()` instead

Comment: @KirillIvlev Thanks for pointing it out, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @charlietfl `is` will return true if any element matches.

Comment: @heelhook because he possibly may have other `input[type="checkbox"]` elements on the same page that are not cover by this logic, so selecting by id's we don't mix them.

Comment: @JanDvorak my bad, have always used filter instead. `is()` uses `filter()` in jQuery source anyway

Answer (score 1):

If I read right, you want to show the div only if all checkboxes are checked.  I created a jsfiddle, and the code is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/jyw9n/

```
<input type=checkbox id="cb1" name="cb1">
<input type=checkbox id="cb2" name="cb2">
<input type=checkbox id="cb3" name="cb3">
<input type=checkbox id="cb4" name="cb4">
<input type=checkbox id="cb5" name="cb5">

<div id="hidden">some stuff</div>

$('#hidden').hide();
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    if(!$('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length)
    {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this as per your logic should also work, but mplungjan Idea is better than this.

```
$(function() {

$("input").click(function() { 
    if($("#cb1").is(":checked") && $("#cb2").is(":checked")  && $("#cb3").is(":checked") &&  $("#cb4").is(":checked") && $("#cb5").is(":checked"))
    {
        $('#hidden').hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#hidden').show();
    }   
});

  })
```

Comment: Except I only counted cb1 - now I think I got it :)

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is you want to hide or show a div by comparing multiple checkboxes. Suppose you want to show a div only when 3 checkbox are selected.

Easy way to do is , gave all the checkboxes same name for which you want to check and bind the function on their click to check for all the 3 checkboxes whether they are checked or not. if all three are checked show div else hide.

```
<input type=checkbox id="cb1" name="cb1">
<input type=checkbox id="cb2" name="cb1">
<input type=checkbox id="cb3" name="cb1">
<input type=checkbox id="cb4" name="cb2">
<input type=checkbox id="cb5" name="cb3">
<div id="hidden">some stuff</div>  

<script>
var $hiddenDiv=$('#hidden');
var hideOrShowDivFlag=false
$('input[name=cb1]').click(function(){
    $("input['cb1']").each(function(){
    hideOrShowDivFlag=($(this).is(":checked"))?true:false
    })
    (hideOrShowDivFlag)?$hiddenDiv.show():$hiddenDiv.hide();
});
```

You can run this code for any set of given checkboxes. Make sure you gave them same name or any common attribute,